# What is the method variable? in C#

Tags: c#, variables, methods

I use C#.

When I defined `Hoge` method below,

```
void Hoge(bool isBar){}
```

I get the Hoge method like below

```
var methodName = this.Hoge as Action<bool>).Method.Name;
```

However, I can't understand what does `this.Hoge` type.
Because, it can assign and casting.

but, it can't give me method name directly.
`this.Hoge.Method.Name;`

and, it also error. `typeof(this.Hoge)`

what is method variable exactly?

Comment: _"it can't give me method name directly"_ - If you're using C# 6.0, you can use `nameof(this.Hoge)`

Comment: Thank you for replying. But, I don't use C# 6.0 suited to 4.0, cause mine C# is Mono's.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile even when I add in the missing bracket. Can you please check it? You need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: `void Hoge(bool isBar){ return false; }`

Comment: @shinriyo The language version and runtime version are two different things. You can compile C#6 code, targeting .NET 4.5

Answer (score 1):

The code you provided isn't valid C# code, so it's very difficult to understand what you're asking. But I *think* you're trying to understand how the expression `this.Hoge` is translated into something that can eventually provide you with the name of the method.

If so, then your code example *should* look something like this:

```
var methodName = ((Action<bool>)this.Hoge).Method.Name;
```

And what that does is to implicitly create an instance of a delegate type (in this case, of the type `Action<bool>`), as if you'd written this:

```
var methodName = new Action<bool>(this.Hoge).Method.Name;
```

And of course, once you have a delegate type, that type has a [`Method` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.method(v=vs.110).aspx), which returns a `MethodInfo` object which in turn, of course, has a `Name` property.

If that is not what you're asking, please improve your question by providing a valid, compilable C# example of what you're asking about, along with a more precisely worded question about that code.

Comment: yes. I'm sorry. I forgot `(`.